# Fade in animation blinks the view

Tags: android, animation

I want to make three text views fade in one after another. I am trying to do this with start animation after finishing first and so on. But it not works for me. Please help

```
            text_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            text_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            text_3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

private void fadingAnimation() {
        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
        fadeIn.setDuration(2000);
        AnimationSet animation1 = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
        final AnimationSet animation2 = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
        final AnimationSet animation3 = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
        animation1.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                text_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text_2.startAnimation(animation2);
            }
        });


        text_1.startAnimation(animation1);

  }
```

Comment: It's normal it is not working... you do your alpha animation on an invisible view, and then only at the end of the animation you make it visible. Instead of the set visibility making the views invisible, just set the alpha to 0 there, and it will work. Also, you don't initialize animation2 and animation3 ...

Comment: can u please give a sample code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your menthod to

```
private void fadingAnimation() {
        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
        fadeIn.setDuration(2000);
        AnimationSet animation1 = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
        final AnimationSet animation2 = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
        final AnimationSet animation3 = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
        animation1.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                text_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text_2.startAnimation(animation2);
            }
        });

 animation2.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                text_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text_3.startAnimation(animation3);
            }
        });


animation3.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation3.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }           
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                 text_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });


        text_1.startAnimation(animation1);

  }
```

Comment: yes, I have the same output earlier. I want to get the animation for three of them